# New column conditional on whether number is even/uneven and on column

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Say i have the following df:

```
id<-rep(1:2,c(7,6))
name<-c('a','t','signal','b','s','e','signal','x','signal','r','s','t','signal')

   id   name
1   1      a
2   1      t
3   1 signal
4   1      b
5   1      s
6   1      e
7   1 signal
8   2      x
9   2 signal
10  2      r
11  2      s
12  2      t
13  2 signal
```

I want to add a new column with a character value conditional on whether the id number is even or not, and whether the string 'signal' is reached in the 'name' column.

For uneven id numbers, and up to including 'signal' for the column 'name' I would like the character T. After the signal, the character should become 'C'.

For even id numbers, and up to including 'signal' for the column 'name' I would like the character C. After the signal, the character should become 'T'.

For the example given, this should result in the following data.frame:

```
id, name    condition
1,  a,      T
1,  t,      T
1,  signal, T
1,  b,      C
1,  s,      C
1,  e,      C
1,  signal  C
2,  x,      C
2,  signal, C
2,  r,      T
2,  s,      T
2,  t,      T
2,  signal  T
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a vectorized solution, but for me it seems as a wroking code.

Data preparation - I add new column to describe the condition

```
id<-rep(1:2,c(7,6))
name<-c('a','t','signal','b','s','e','signal','x','signal','r','s','t','signal')
df <- data.frame(id, name)
df$condition <- rep("X", nrow(df))
```

I need to control two states: (i) if the `signal` has switched; (ii) if the id changes `last` (from even to odd and other way). Then I read row by row and update the condition state along with two variables.

```
signal <- F
last <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    # id changed - reset signal
    if (last != (df[i, "id"] %% 2)) signal <- F
    if(!signal){
        df[i,"condition"] <- ifelse(df[i,"id"] %% 2, "T", "C")
    } else {
        df[i, "condition"] <- ifelse(df[i,"id"] %% 2, "C", "T")
    }
    # signal is on
    if (df[i, "name"] == "signal") signal <- T
    # save last id (even or odd)
    last <- df[i, "id"] %% 2
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm!!! I would have never figured out this myself!

Answer (score 0):

We could make use of `%%` with `==` to create the column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(ind = (cumsum(lag(name, default = name[1]) == 'signal')>0) + 1, 
           condition = c('T', 'C')[ifelse(id %%2 > 0, ind, 
                 as.integer(factor(ind, levels = rev(unique(ind)))))] ) %>% 
    select(-ind)
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
#      id   name condition
#   <int>  <chr>     <chr>
# 1     1      a         T
# 2     1      t         T
# 3     1 signal         T
# 4     1      b         C
# 5     1      s         C
# 6     1      e         C
# 7     1 signal         C
# 8     2      x         C
# 9     2 signal         C
#10     2      r         T
#11     2      s         T
#12     2      t         T
#13     2 signal         T
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id, name, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. Unfortunately, I get the following error: "Éxpecting a single value". The previous answers worked though!

Comment: @DavidMaij  This was based on your example and it is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
id <- rep(1:2,c(7,6))
name <- c('a','t','signal','b','s','e','signal','x','signal','r','s','t','signal')
df <- data.frame(id, name)

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(FirstSignalIndex=min(which(name=='signal'))) %>%
  mutate(condition = ifelse((id %% 2)==0, 
                      ifelse(row_number()>FirstSignalIndex, 'T', 'C'),
                      ifelse(row_number()>FirstSignalIndex, 'C', 'T')))
```

Hope this helps!